# How to force a leader on SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a 5-node SolrCloud (Solr 7.0) with an external 3-node Zookeeper ensemble. There is one collection called "production" that is sharded to 5 shards with a replication factor of 5. See the screenshot below:

[image]

shard5 was struggling to elect a new leader for a long time and other cores were complaining with the following error:

> azsolr1 solr: 2018-08-28 19:32:43.575 ERROR (qtp1124317168-9304) [c:production s:shard2 r:core_node9 x:production_shard2_replica_n4] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection: production slice: shard5

After restarting all nodes one by one (I even restarted the zookeeper nodes), I had no luck in electing the only active replica (azsolr1) as the leader. I then unloaded the 4 replicas with the 'down' state using the [CoreAdmin API UNLOAD](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/coreadmin-api.html#CoreAdminAPI-UNLOAD) command which caused the replicas to disappear completely.

With that setup, trying to force the leader of the shard using the [Collection API FORCELEADER](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-forceleader) does nothing. I also tried this before unloading the cores.

Here is the current status:

[image]

Why can't Solr just elect the only active replica for shard 5 as the leader? Isn't this obvious, especially after forcing the leader on the shard?

Assuming the leader was elected successfully somehow, do I recreate the replicas that I deleted using the [Collection API ADDREPLICA](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-addreplica)? In this case, should I reuse the same `instanceDir` and `dataDir` of the deleted replicas? Or I just let it replicate from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting `azsolr1` which was hosting the only replica for `shard5` forced the election of the leader. Sounds crazy, but that was it.
After doing that, I added the other 4 replicas using the `ADDREPLICA` command.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

one collection with 3 replicas (solr1 --> was a leader before, solr2,  solr3). one of the shards has no leader!  and I did these steps :

1 - stop **solr2** and **solr3**

2- call FORCE LEADER API  (`http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=FORCELEADER&collection=your_collection_name&shard=shard1`)

3 - after a few minutes solr1 elected as a leader